# How to convert rows into columns in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot, laravel-query-builder

I am totally new in web developing... What I want is this:

[image: row records converted into columns in Excel]

The records that i get have three main columns, 'DateTime', 'meter_type', 'value'... Now in here, meter_type have same values i.e. like from 1 to 8 (in image, it is 72 to 79) for different values of DateTime and value... As an example, at DateTime: `2016-06-23 00:01:00`, i get `8` different values for all `8` different meter types and similarly at DateTime: `2016-06-23 00:02:00`, i will get new set of 8 values for all meter_types...

Now what I want is, to group 'DateTime' column  for different 'meter_type' i.e., in this case (above example), I want 9 columns (in total), 1 column for DateTime and remaining all 8 columns depicting 8 meter_type and records for these columns will be `value` of them... Please refer image for more clarification...

And I want to do this in travel using query builders or eloquent... I googled this, but I didn't found anything useful in travel for what I want... Please help me out here... documentations or properly detailed examples for achieving what I want will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look like a perfect use for the group by method on collections:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-groupby

That way if you do

```
$collection->groupBy('meter_type');
```

You'll have an array using the meter type as key and all records regarding that meter type in each.